# How to add transparent background while open the side menu in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, transparent, side-menu

I am using left side menu from [jonkykong/SideMenu](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu). If I open side menu I need transparent background view and if i close then background should change to its original colour. For that i am trying to set alpha value for side menu.

I have tried two ways:

**1) Here i have installed `pod 'SideMenu'` and added below code:**

```
 import UIKit
 import SideMenu

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sideMenuConfig()
    }
    func sideMenuConfig(){
        // Define the menus
        SideMenuManager.default.menuLeftNavigationController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UISideMenuNavigationController") as? UISideMenuNavigationController
        var set = SideMenuSettings()
        set.presentationStyle.presentingEndAlpha = 1
        SideMenuManager.default.menuPresentMode = .menuSlideIn
        SideMenuManager.default.menuFadeStatusBar  = false
        SideMenuManager.default.menuAddPanGestureToPresent(toView: self.navigationController!.navigationBar)
        SideMenuManager.default.menuAddScreenEdgePanGesturesToPresent(toView: self.navigationController!.view)
    }
}
```

here why pod not recognising SideMenuSettings.

> error: Use of unresolved identifier 'SideMenuSettings'

**2) Updated pod to swift 5 pod `'SideMenu', '~> 6.0'` and below code:**

```
 import UIKit
 import SideMenu

 class ViewController: UIViewController, SideMenuNavigationControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        menuSettings()
    }
    func menuSettings(){
        let menu = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SideMenuNavigationController") as! SideMenuNavigationController
        menu.blurEffectStyle = nil
        var set = SideMenuSettings()
        set.statusBarEndAlpha = 0
        set.presentationStyle = SideMenuPresentationStyle.menuSlideIn
        set.presentationStyle.presentingEndAlpha = 0.5
        set.menuWidth = min(view.frame.width, view.frame.height) * 0.90
        menu.settings = set
        SideMenuManager.default.leftMenuNavigationController = menu
    }
}
```

here background view also moving with side menu like below
How add give alpha value to side menu in swift.

Please help with the side menu code.

[image]

Comment: Try - SideMenuSettings.presentationStyle.presentingEndAlpha = 1.

Comment: @Aditya, error `Use of unresolved identifier 'SideMenuSettings'` ..Please do help

Comment: Change `SideMenuSettings().presentationStyle.presentingEndAlpha = 1`

Comment: @Aditya, same error `Use of unresolved identifier 'SideMenuSettings'`

Comment: You can check  jonkykong/SideMenu Example project by running it.

Comment: Try `let presentationStyle = selectedPresentationStyle() ` and `presentationStyle.presentingEndAlpha = 0` and assign `var settings = SideMenuSettings()` and `settings.presentationStyle = presentationStyle`

Comment: @KishanBhatiya, not working, `Use of unresolved identifier 'selectedPresentationStyle'` and `Use of unresolved identifier 'SideMenuSettings'` errors..... is there any other way.. please do help

Comment: @KishanBhatiya, I have updated code.. please have a look

Comment: just remove `let presentationStyle = selectedPresentationStyle()` ,`presentationStyle.presentingEndAlpha = 0` and add `settings.presentationStyle. presentingEndAlpha = 0`

Comment: @KishanBhatiya, Use of unresolved identifier 'SideMenuSettings'... actually pod not recognising `SideMenuSettings`  i dont know why.. i have imported SideMenu in project

Comment: @KishanBhatiya, which pod u have installed `pod 'SideMenu', '~> 6.0'` or `pod 'SideMenu', '~> 5.0'` ....... in Swift 5 i have demo project can i share the github link so   u can find the issue quickely

Comment: Yes, add `pod 'SideMenu'` in your podfile which install latest pods

Comment: @KishanBhatiya, yes.. if yours demo project in github, please share the link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206785/discussion-between-kishan-bhatiya-and-devios).

Comment: @DevIos try to check my comment in chat

Comment: menu.presentationStyle.presentingEndAlpha = 0.7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just create a subclass of SideMenuNavigationController and set the presentationStyle's **backgroundColor** and **presentingEndAlpha** properties in it. From now on, you can use your CustomSideMenuNavigationController as your SideMenuNavigationController.

```
class CustomSideMenuNavigationController: SideMenuNavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)

        self.presentationStyle = .menuSlideIn
        self.presentationStyle.backgroundColor = .white
        self.presentationStyle.presentingEndAlpha = 0.7

        self.statusBarEndAlpha = 0.0
        self.menuWidth = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 5) * 4
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank yu very much for your answer. It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

For Transparent background need to change value of **menuAnimationFadeStrength**.

- Demo::

SideMenuManager.default.menuAnimationFadeStrength = 0.5

Comment: thank u, its perfectly worked for option One... have u tried second option updating pod in swift 5 pod 'SideMenu', '~> 6.0'